# Foundation 6 grid programmatic column removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using foundation 6 in a new project and stumbled upon an issue.
I have a grid with and I want to hide a column (which I want to show again later), the problem is that if I hide the column, it does not reorder all the other columns, I tried by just hiding it with jQuery and by hiding it with Foundation's `hide` class (which, I guess, is basically the same thing).
The only way I was able to achieve the wanted functionality is by actually removing the column completely, but I need to show it again later so this is not an option.

Please take a look at the fiddle to maybe get a better idea of what I need. 
(You will have to Run the script again after click one of the buttons)

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/875ascsk/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is you are not using the classes properly, for example the size of column should be applied to the column not the row elements.

`<div class="column">`

Should be:

`<div class="small-4 column">`

https://jsfiddle.net/875ascsk/4/

Comment: wow, thanks, I just saw in a foundation template people using just `column` together with `small-up-4`, `medium-6` in the `row`.
My guess is that now I would just need to add `small-4` and `medium-6` to each `column`?

Comment: @LastTemplar should always be on the column, I've worked with Foundation 5 and I've never seen it placed on the row.

Comment: [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/templates-previews-sites-f6/portfolio.html) is the example I used

Comment: @LastTemplar I see that is a special type of grid where the columns are spaced on their index so "hiding" it would not affect their positions